# How to get AWS email address for a user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

In these docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-user.html

we can get a user with:

```
aws iam get-user --user-name Bob
```

and the result is:

```
{
    "User": {
        "UserName": "Bob",
        "Path": "/",
        "CreateDate": "2012-09-21T23:03:13Z",
        "UserId": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Bob"
    }
}
```

but how do we get this user's email address?

Comment: here is the complete `aws iam` commands - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/  I do not see "email" there anywhere fml

Comment: Email Address is not a standard field for IAM Users. You could store such information in a **tag** on the IAM User if desired.

Answer (score 1):

IAM users do not have an email address property. Are you sure you're referring to IAM users?

The root user for your AWS account will have an email address associated with it, but there is only one of these users.

Also, if you have a Cognito user pool, these users can have an email address associated with them.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-iam-user.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html